# Emulator stops working after i restart the Android studio

Tags: android, wear-os

Hy there. I have made the app for the android wear . I got it install and then when next day I start it I mean my android studio and the emulator , the Emulator stops working and error pop out saying "Emulator stops working"

So I do not know what is a main problem. So the wear app that I have made is creating problem or is there could be another problem?? please tell me waiting for your help . thanks

Comment: did you saw the logcat for any errors ? or did you tried creating another emulator ?

Comment: Yeah there is nothing in Log cat

Comment: Ihave two emulator for android wear I checked on both one start normal and other gets crashed when starting it , but after closing and then cleaning all the .lock files of avd it starts again without problem

Comment: ok then there is nothing to worry about the emulator that crashes might have some bugs or configuration issues. delete it and create a new one ...

Comment: @Darkie thanks for your replyI was thinking the same as the AS avds for wearable are not so much flexible . So do you know any other online or any other good emulator for the wearable or android watches

Comment: I haven't done much on wearables but in android documentation it is mentioned how to Set Up an Android Wear Emulator or Device
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupEmulator

Comment: As far as I think , I think that the training out there is not enough as these are general documents and the developers are just moving towards it and on internet there is just a little data available on the internet.  So as described on the link that you have shared I have followed the instructions but that is of no use. I mean that is not so much useful those are just general to start the things

Comment: But thanks anyways for removing my confusion about AVD @Darkie

Comment: no problem I faced the same issues when I started working on google glass there is very little data avliable but you have to search the internet to get something :D . documentation just gives the head start .... Glad that I helped :)

Comment: [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) is a great emulator, as far as I tested it. Way better than the built-in Android Studio emulator

Comment: @snow we are talking about android wear emulators ? is there genymotion emulator for the wears???